# Binding Combobox to display integer values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, converters

I Bind a ComboBox to an Entity.
I want the Combobox to display on each Item multiple values of different format (Integer, String and DateTime values), like this:

```
Item#1) 100  - Description - 01/01/2013

Item#2) 101  - Description - 01/01/2013
```

But the ComboBox only displays the SQL char (C# string) values, the others are empty:

```
Item#1)     - Description -

Item#2)     - Description -
```

I have to use a Converter, am I on the wrong path, or there is a simpler solution?

In XAML

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tSCHEDEViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:TSCHEDE, CreateList=True}" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SchedaTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KSCHEDA}" Width="60"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DArticolo}" Width="200"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" - " Width="40"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DStorico}" Width="150"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SchedaTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="23,129,0,0" Name="tSCHEDEComboBox1" SelectedValuePath="KScheda" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
```

The .edmx Model

```
<EntityType Name="TSCHEDE">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="KSCHEDA" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="KSCHEDA" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="KLINEA" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="DSCHEDA" Type="char" MaxLength="30" />
      <Property Name="DSTORICO" Type="datetime" />
      <Property Name="FINSMAN" Type="char" MaxLength="1" />
      <Property Name="DNOTE" Type="char" MaxLength="255" />
      <Property Name="FCANC" Type="char" MaxLength="1" />
      <Property Name="DArticolo" Type="char" MaxLength="60" />
      <Property Name="FFIGLIA" Type="char" MaxLength="1" />
    </EntityType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have problem with case sensitive. When you binding you must exactly rewrite name of the variable.

Try this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tSCHEDEViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:TSCHEDE, CreateList=True}" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SchedaTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KSCHEDA}" Width="60"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DARTICOLO" Width="200"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" - " Width="40"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DSTORICO}" Width="150"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In `SelectedValuePath` you also have wrong variable, change it to `SelectedValuePath="KSCHEDA"`.